# Optimal mulling temperature?

Tags: temperature, mulling, preparation-for-drinking

Taste-wise, at least in my opinion, the hotter the mulled beer the better. Except past certain point the alcohol starts evaporating so quickly you end up losing most of it before you start drinking.

How should I heat the beer - what temperature, what heating method - to get it as hot as possible without losing alcohol content?

Answer (score 3):

**Almost but not boiling**.

I've been over a few recipes and "simmering" seems to be the consensus.